# ntext/text/image datatypes in SQL server 2016 CTP 3

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I am using SQL server 2016 CTP 3, as per documentation, ntext/text/image datatypes are not supported but I tested this by creating new DB and all these datatype still works.

Database compatibility mode is SQL server 2016.

Am I missing something?

Comment: may be those changes not implemented yet

Comment: Amazing how you do not manage to read documentation. A dictionary is in order to look up the meaning of "deprecated". And what "next version" means when it is said in the 2016 documentation (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143729.aspx). So, no, your hypothesis is wrong, as is your conclusion.

Comment: @TomTom Thank You, My bad :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143729.aspx) those data types are *deprecated*, not removed. They will be removed in a future version but will still be usable in 2016. So this is just a strong message not to use them in anything new.

Comment: Adding to Sami's point, new features are typically not tested beyond "do no harm". That means the new feature is only verified to not break existing apps that use the deprecated feature(s)  when run side-by-side. There's no assurance that the new feature will work with a deprecated feature.